# How to access and update Sqlite db file stored locally[asset folder] in project file using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-sqlite

I have a `sqlite db` file stored in `assets` folder of my `cordova` project ,which i want to access inside my application and also want to update the db.

So far i had a look on i found there `cordova sqlite plug-in` which can create a sqlite db and update it,but not sure how to update a existing db file from asset folder in cordova

Here is my below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="index.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/conf-room1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/custom_color.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script>

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var db = "";

function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SoccerPlayer');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SoccerPlayer (Name TEXT NOT NULL, Club TEXT NOT NULL)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Test1", "Team1")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Test2", "Team2")');
}

function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM SoccerPlayer', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}


function querySuccess(tx,result){
        var playerlist = document.getElementById("SoccerPlayerList");
        var players = "";
        alert("The show is on");
        var len = result.rows.length;
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            alert(result.rows.item(i).Name + result.rows.item(i).Club);
            players = players + '<li><a href="#"><p class="record">'+result.rows.item(i).Name+'</p><p class="small">Club '+result.rows.item(i).Club+'</p></a></li>';
        }

        playerlist.innerHTML = players;
        $("#SoccerPlayerList").listview("refresh");
}


function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}


function successCB() {
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}


function onDeviceReady() {
    <!--db = window.openDatabase("SimpleTestOne", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);-->
   db =  window.openDatabase({name: "SimpleTestOne.db", createFromLocation: 1});
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
    </script>


</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Soccer Player</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="SoccerPlayerList">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end of Soccer Player Page--->
</body>
</html>
```

**Note: I have SimpleTestOne.db in my assets folder**

Comment: You can access that DB file using this path `file:///android_asset/www/DBFilePathHere`. But i suggest you to create using SQLite database and update that db file and their is no need to installed plugin without installing plugin you can also work with it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.can you put up some code samples how to update that db records

Comment: Have you already created database for your app using SQLite DB  including inserting data etc..?

Comment: Yes i have already a db which i have created using sqlite browser.I just want to access db and update it using some queries.

Comment: Try with my answer and let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay let me check...

Answer (score 3):

**You can try with below `Snippet.`**

`This snippet contains all the part from Data base creation to Insert , Edit , Delete , Update and Display data` of your database.

**Note:** `Change your Database name and Table name and Database fields here whatever you want to keep`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        var currentRow;
        // Populate the database
        //
        function populateDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name,number)');
        }

        // Query the database
        //
        function queryDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
        }

        function searchQueryDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM DEMO where name like ('%"+ document.getElementById("txtName").value + "%')",
                    [], querySuccess, errorCB);
        }
        // Query the success callback
        //
        function querySuccess(tx, results) {
            var tblText='<table id="t01"><tr><th>ID</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Number</th></tr>';
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var tmpArgs=results.rows.item(i).id + ",'" + results.rows.item(i).name
                        + "','" + results.rows.item(i).number+"'";
                tblText +='<tr onclick="goPopup('+ tmpArgs + ');"><td>' + results.rows.item(i).id +'</td><td>'
                        + results.rows.item(i).name +'</td><td>' + results.rows.item(i).number +'</td></tr>';
            }
            tblText +="</table>";
            document.getElementById("tblDiv").innerHTML =tblText;
        }

        //Delete query
        function deleteRow(tx) {
          tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM DEMO WHERE id = ' + currentRow, [], queryDB, errorCB);
        }

        // Transaction error callback
        //
        function errorCB(err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
        }

        // Transaction success callback
        //
        function successCB() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
        }

         // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }

        //Insert query
        //
        function insertDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (name,number) VALUES ("' +document.getElementById("txtName").value
                    +'","'+document.getElementById("txtNumber").value+'")');
        }

        function goInsert() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }

        function goSearch() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(searchQueryDB, errorCB);
        }

        function goDelete() {
             var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
             db.transaction(deleteRow, errorCB);
             document.getElementById('qrpopup').style.display='none';
        }

        //Show the popup after tapping a row in table
        //
        function goPopup(row,rowname,rownum) {
            currentRow=row;
            document.getElementById("qrpopup").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("editNameBox").value = rowname;
            document.getElementById("editNumberBox").value = rownum;
        }

        function editRow(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('UPDATE DEMO SET name ="'+document.getElementById("editNameBox").value+
                    '", number= "'+document.getElementById("editNumberBox").value+ '" WHERE id = '
                    + currentRow, [], queryDB, errorCB);
        }
        function goEdit() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(editRow, errorCB);
            document.getElementById('qrpopup').style.display='none';
        }

    </script>
```

`I am using this code for one of my app and it's working fine.`

**Edit 1 :**

**NOTE :** `Please place your db file in wwww directory like for e.g projectpath/www/dbname.db`.

`For accessing db file from asset folder.`

```
window.openDatabase({name: "dbname.db", createFromLocation: 1});
```

**Edit 2:**

`Just install below plugin in your app`.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git
```

`And Try this.`

```
 var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db", createFromLocation: 1});
```

Comment: @AbhijitChakra have you added any js file in your page ? Like cordova.js etc.....

Comment: now its working but is it creating a new db or its taking the data from db file which in asset folder

Comment: No it will create new DB. but if you push your database file into your app using ddms and then pass that database name in this code then it will work with that.

Comment: Do u know how to access the db file inside asset folder?OR how to give path of that db so that it wil open in code

Comment: @AbhijitChakra Have you get it worked bro ? let me know.

Comment: this is not working...window.openDatabase({name: "dbname.db", createFromLocation: 1});  is it working on your side

Comment: @AbhijitChakra Have you define it in var db variable like this `db = window.openDatabase({name: "dbname.db", createFromLocation: 1});`.

Comment: yes for you reference i am pasting my code.just have a look.Please run this code at your end.

Comment: @AbhijitChakra Are you sure you are not forgetting to add window in `window.openDatabase` please cross check that once.

Comment: Yes i missed it on onDeviceReady() function and now i added but still no luck

Comment: @AbhijitChakra what is Logcat showing ? any error or message ?

Comment: 04-21 12:53:16.431 25192-25198/? E/jdwp: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
04-21 12:53:19.031 25192-25192/? E/Web Console: No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin. at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js:24
04-21 12:53:19.031 25192-25192/? E/Web Console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Not enough arguments at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:68
This i am getting, but i am able to see my first screen but no data coming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109814/discussion-between-jaydroider-and-abhijit-chakra).