# I want to create a sample project using Sqlite plugin (Cordova) in Hybrid Mobile Apllication?

Tags: javascript, android, html, sqlite, cordova

I referred the code mentioned in https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage. Database file is not generated. Any help should be appreciated.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'my.db', location: 'default'});

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer primary key, data text, data_num integer)');

    // demonstrate PRAGMA:
    db.executeSql("pragma table_info (test_table);", [], function(res) {
      console.log("PRAGMA res: " + JSON.stringify(res));
    });

    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", ["test", 100], function(tx, res) {
      console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
      console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");

      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select count(id) as cnt from test_table;", [], function(tx, res) {
          console.log("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length + " -- should be 1");
          console.log("res.rows.item(0).cnt: " + res.rows.item(0).cnt + " -- should be 1");
        });
      });

    }, function(e) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: cordova.js file included in your html? Any error trace?

Comment: Have you checked in `DDMS` for database ? Your database will be in you package name folder.

Comment: Where do i get cordova.js file, Is there any source from which i can download it? @Gandhi

Comment: I already checked DDMS , any database is not created @jaydroider

Comment: @AnjaliPatel Check my given answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743158/how-to-access-and-update-sqlite-db-file-stored-locallyasset-folder-in-project/36745708#36745708

Comment: @AnjaliPatel cordova.js file gets generated automatically in your root folder once you do platform build. All you need to do is to include the file in your html mentioning the proper relative path

Comment: cordova.js  file is  generated automatically in platform folder but in DDMS while running the app the database file physically not present anywhere.

Comment: cordova.js  file is  generated automatically in platform folder but in DDMS while running the app the database file physically not present anywhere.                         But by default the webview.db file is generated. @Gandhi

Comment: @AnjaliPatel first call to plugin using this line - "window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'my.db', location: 'default'});" succeeded for you? Are you using cordova version 6.0 or greater, as the plugin page says older version is not supported

Comment: Thanks @Gandhi for help .Can I get  your contact details/email id ,as I would like to discuss the issue  for expediting the resolution.

Comment: @AnjaliPatel you can write to me on gandhirajan.n@gmail.com

Comment: @AnjaliPatel did u managed to crack it?

Answer (score -1):

**Please provide the file location in default**

var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'my.db', location: 'abc.txt'});

Comment: As far as i read in the documentation of cordova sqlite storage plugin, location refers to the path where the db file gets created. So i guess specifying file name for location argument is not right.